# How to use terraform variable into gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, devops

I am working on a command in gitlab-ci.yml where I need to read some value from a terraform named **locals.tf** 
Below is the terraform code

```
locals {
  lambda_edge_name = format(var.resource_name_pattern, "cloudfront-edge")
}
```

yml code

```
lambda-deletion:
  stage: lambda-deletion
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  script:
    lambda_name = //read_terraform_value_here
    echo $lambda_name;
```

I want to read the **lambda_edge_name** into a variable in **gitlab-ci.yml** file. 
I tried many things(which are not even worth mentioning here), but seems like I am stuck at this.

Comment: Usually if you want to read terraform variables as enviornment variables, you would add `TF_VAR_` in front of the variable name, or in your case `TF_VAR_lambda_name`. Although, I am not sure what does the local variable have to do with the YAML code. Or you are asking how to read a value from the terraform variable?

Comment: @MarkoE yes that is exactly my question- How to read a value from the terraform variable

Answer (score 0):

You could just export an [`output`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/outputs) and then read it

```
locals {
  lambda_edge_name = format("${var.resource_name_pattern}-something", "cloudfront-edge")
}

output "lambda_edge_name" {
  value = local.lambda_edge_name
}
```

Then in your script run:

```
lambda_name =$(terraform output lambda_edge_name)
```

---

If you can format this output without using variables, you may use [`hclq`](https://github.com/mattolenik/hclq), for example:

```
locals {
  lambda_edge_name = "cloudfront-edge"
}
```

Then:

```
cat locals.tf | hclq get 'locals.lambda_edge_name'
```

Comment: the first approach is giving an error. Pipeline is failing stating terraform: command not found. Same goes for second one, giving an error lambda_name: command not found

Comment: Looks like your base image `registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest` does not have terraform, consider using an image that has terraform, I would not go for an approach using regex here, so just stick with terraform cli, or tools like HCLQ that actually evaluate your expressions

Comment: If I read your reply in [Marko E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75531444/how-to-use-terraform-variable-into-gitlab-ci-yml/75532415?noredirect=1#comment133262999_75531444)'s comment I understand that you want something else, like you want to assign a value for `resource_name_pattern`, I am confused

Comment: No. I want to read the value of lambda_edge_name in a yml file. I am trying to change the image. Maybe the above solution works.